# AjaxElementLocatorFactory = Implicit or Explicit

Tags: selenium, selenium2, java, selenium-webdriver, page-objects

I'm looking for solution in page factory to wait.

I don't want to use something like Implicit wait, but something like Explicit.

I read about AjaxElementLocatorFactory, but I'm not sure that it works like Implicit or Explicit. So can anyone help me in knowing how it works and how to use it?

Comment: Why not use the explicit wait itself?

Comment: becouse i wrote somewhere that in page factory there is no possible to use Explicit

Answer (score 3):

It uses an Explicit Wait, not implicit in the [AjaxElementLocatorFactory](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ceaf3da79542024becdda5953059dfbb96fb3a90/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/AjaxElementLocatorFactory.java). Though, it is not the same as the [FluentWait](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/23f66a969e2e26b97414293c481bf25c7e4a9358/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.java) that is used elsewhere.

The factory creates an [AjaxElementLocator](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ceaf3da79542024becdda5953059dfbb96fb3a90/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/AjaxElementLocator.java). It uses a [SlowLoadableComponent](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ceaf3da79542024becdda5953059dfbb96fb3a90/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/SlowLoadableComponent.java) to initiate the wait, which can be found in the [get](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ceaf3da79542024becdda5953059dfbb96fb3a90/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/SlowLoadableComponent.java#L47-L72) function.

To answer the comment by FDM on NarendraC's answer:

> Can you elaborate when you say the code will wait for 15 seconds? Is this from the moment you call any method on an element, for that element only?

Yes, it will wait up to 15 seconds for each element **ANYTIME** they are accessed. **AjaxElementLocator ignores the CacheLookup tag**. Skipping over a lot of the PageFactory internals, this can be evident in the [LocatingElementHandler](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ceaf3da79542024becdda5953059dfbb96fb3a90/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/internal/LocatingElementHandler.java#L38). It will call locator.findElement() on each element which will trigger the findElement in the [AjaxElementLocator](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ceaf3da79542024becdda5953059dfbb96fb3a90/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/AjaxElementLocator.java#L84-L93) which triggers the wait in the [SlowLoadableComponent](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ceaf3da79542024becdda5953059dfbb96fb3a90/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/SlowLoadableComponent.java).

Answer (score 0):

I use [PageFactory](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) with [AjaxElementLocatorFactory](http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/59b77199ceca4f56/f29355bbdaba6db9?lnk=gst&q=AjaxElementLocatorFactory) - PageFactory is a support class for the Selenium 2 Page Objects pattern which you are using, and the AjaxElementLocatorFactory is the factory for the element locators. In your case the constructor will looks like:

```
public GoogleResultsPage() { 
    PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 15), this);
}
```

This code will wait maximum of 15 seconds until the elements specified by annotations will appear on the page, in your case the homePageLink which will be located by xpath. You will not need to use ElementPresent class.

AjaxElementLocatorFactory uses SlowLoadableComponent internally.

Comment: Can you elaborate when you say the code will wait for 15 seconds? Is this from the moment you call any method on an element, for that element only?